# Renewing long lived token without user interaction?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authorization

Let me start by saying that authorization, tokens, and this whole process confuse the hell out of me so I hope I can convey what I'm trying to understand!

I have a WordPress blog for which I'm using a very basic plugin I wrote to authorize Facebook to my personal account. I am granting user_photos and manage_pages permissions to allow me to display photo galleries on the blog from both my own account and a page related to the blog. I am only ever concerned with authorizing Facebook to my own account.

I'm using the API to generate an auth token and I'm storing that token in the WP database to reuse it. I've verified that I have a long-lived token. This all works perfectly right now. My gallery displays exactly as I want to anyone who visits the site.

What I don't understand, and don't know how to test, is what will happen right now when this token expires. My assumption is that if a user comes to my site once that has happened they will see some gibberish/errors where the gallery should be. I have read through the "[Scenario 4](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/)" here and it looks kind of like what I'm dealing with but I don't get where the new short-lived token comes from that can be then exchanged for the long-lived token.

Can I generate that new short-lived token automatically to re-authorize the app without any interaction from me, or am I going to have to make a note to myself to visit the plugin every month to make sure it's not going to expire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to renew the user access token without the specific user itself. Would make the whole system void anyway. But, the long living token lasts for 60 days, so you would have to login to your app once in a while.

Better: Afaik you can get a page token for a page that lives forever by calling `/me/accounts` with a long living (60 days) user access token. So that works at least for pages. Data from user accounts are not meant to be published somewhere anyway. But then again, if you just want to read stuff from a facebook page, you can use an app access token instead:

```
$app_access_token = APPID . '|' . APPSECRET;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - so from what you've said and reading over the [Page Connections Reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#connections) I can do exactly what I want as long as I manage all the photos through the page rather than myself. I don't need any sort of additional authorization. Does that sound right?

Comment: Exactly, as long as you read everything from a page, you are fine. It will only be a problem if you want to EDIT stuff on the page, in that case you need a page token. For albums/photos of a page you dont need any access token, for the feed you can use any access token, meaning you can also use the static app access token i mentioned in my post.